# ffmpeg - escaping special characters

Tags: ffmpeg, screen-recording

I want to record screen using ffmpeg. Here is a simple command which I use and works fine

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone Array (Full HD 1080P PC Camera Audio)" -f gdigrab -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 500x500 -framerate 30 -i desktop -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency  -movflags +faststart  "recording.mp4"
```

But I have another USB mic (**Microphone 1:2 (USB PnP Sound Device)**), which has a colon (:) in its name. When I use it for recording, it gives error

```
[dshow @ 0000028f718db740] Malformed dshow input string.
audio=Microphone 1:2 (USB PnP Sound Device): I/O error
```

I have tried to escape colon sign with **\** & **\\** but still get same error. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

sorry I can't comment but have you tried using ' instead of " for the name?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but that is actually treated like part of device name. And gives error ````Could not find audio only device with name ['Microphone] among source devices of type audio````

Comment: I found another post here that maybe can help you:
https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19820/ffmpeg-afade-plugin-how-to-specify-time-155-if-colon-separates-filter-paramet

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that \\ too, but it gives same error. ````Malformed dshow input string.
audio=Microphone 1\\:2 (USB PnP Sound Device): I/O error````

Comment: Have you tried to check if using the alternative device names help here: 
```ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy```

Comment: Yeah I have tried and alternate name works, but unfortunately I am using this in an app and can't have these alternative names there. So need to find a way to escape this.